# How to Union List and Anonymous Type in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have this code: values of resultList, comes from a stored procedure in Entity Framework and type is `List<spGetAllItems_Result>`.

I want to union defaultitem and resultList in linq lambda

```
var defaultitem = new
        {
            Title = "Default",
            MixParam = "0"
        };

        dpBackRefrence.DataSource = resultList.Select(x => new
        {
            Title = x.Title,
            MixParam = x.MixParam
        }).Distinct();
        dpBackRefrence.DataBind();
```

How can I union defaultitem and result?

Comment: The two lists needs to have the same type, or you must construct a LINQ query that makes them the same. If not the same type, then at least there has to be type compatibility, such as implementing a common interface (which the result then is a collection of), or through inheritance.

Comment: Why not to just check it and add it if needed? It's a one-liner: `if (!resultList.Any(x => x.Title == "Default" && x.MixParam == 0)) resultList.Add(new spGetAllItems_Result {  Title = "Default", MixParam = "0" });`